# More problems with the background of the new CardView

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I have been using the the CardView compatibility library for a small project of mine.

All went fine with all my devices,

**EXCEPT when I have flashed a few days ago my Nexus 7 with the Android 5 image.**

This is the result I get

- **BEFORE** (on APIs below 21)

[image]

- **AFTER** (on a Nexus 7 with a brand new flashed Android 5)

[image]

Does anybody have a clue?

---

---

---

This is the layout I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/cardlayout"
android:layout_width="320dp"
android:layout_height="130dp"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp"
 >

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="117dp" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:foreground="@android:color/transparent"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/radius"
        card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/elevation" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/ll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/my_foreground_selector"
            android:padding="@dimen/elevation" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="117dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/abc_menu_dropdown_panel_holo_light"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image"
                        android:layout_width="96dp"
                        android:layout_height="96dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/gelato_na_nb" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/image_not_available"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/image_loading"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="#7A7A7A"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/progress"
                        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Inverse"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:indeterminateDrawable="@anim/progress_dialog_anim"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#795548"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/address"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="TextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextView"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#ff5722" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ratinglabel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="@string/rating"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="#ffc107"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/filler"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text=" "
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/rating"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="@string/rating"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="#ffc107"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/filler2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="  "
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                <RatingBar
                    android:id="@+id/ratingbar"
                    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/open"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="@color/green"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

This is my selector **`my_foreground_selector.xml`**:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">

<item android:state_pressed="true"

    android:drawable="@drawable/my_foregound_pressed"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/my_foregound_unpressed"/>
</selector>
```

This is my selector **`my_foregound_pressed.xml`**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:left="@dimen/padding"
    android:right="@dimen/padding"
    android:bottom="@dimen/padding"
    android:top="@dimen/padding">

    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/card_pressed"/>
        <corners android:radius="@dimen/radius"/>


    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

This is my selector **`my_foregound_unpressed.xml`**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:left="@dimen/padding"
    android:right="@dimen/padding"
    android:bottom="@dimen/padding"
    android:top="@dimen/padding">

    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
        <corners android:radius="@dimen/radius"/>


    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new elevation attribute in Lollipop lifts the specified view up to a certain z value, which may position it over any other views you've specified in your XML regardless of them being further "down" your hierarchy.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <View
        android:elevation="5dp"
        .... />

    <!-- This view will be positioned under the above, 
         one, even though it is defined further down
         layout file -->
    <View 
        android:elevation="0dp" 
        ... />

</FrameLayout>
```

So, to get your content on top of your card, either set an equal amount of elevation to your LinearLayout with id="@+id/layout", or move it inside your CardView.